# How do I update the default database in ASP.NET 2013?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

So I created a website in ASP.NET 2013 and went through the login so the sample db would be created. Then I added some tables. Now I wanted to customize the AspNetUsers table with my own properties that I add to the ApplicationUser class. However when I add properties to the class and try to run the Update-Database command in the PackageManagerConsole, it fails with a "The parameter is incorrect" message. I thought this would be the way to go as I believe this is considered CodeFirst. This is an ASP.NET 4.5 VB Web Forms App.

Comment: I'm a little lost with your first statement, are you using forms authentication?

Comment: Maybe run the command Add-migration [name] first? Or when you have AutoMigration set to true, it should go automatically on the next login.